# Fill Spring model attribute with value return from completion of Thread Excecution

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

I am using Spring 3.0 framework

I have a Problem regarding thread and its result.
My project has many controllers and their Methods.

I have created one thread which will be called in one of the Method of Controller and i want that its result should be added in model attribute because i want to show result in JSP.

Problem is that thought i am adding thread result in model attribute bit its result is null in JSP. because use is not using currently that controller.

Examlpe :

```
    Spring Controller{

    //mapping
    String controllerMethod1(Model model){

    }

    //mapping
    String controllerMethod2(Model model){
      //thread will calling on this controller method
       //new myThread
      var result=new myThread.start();

      model.addattr("res",result);
    }

    //mapping
    String controllerMethod3(Model model){

    }

    //mapping
    String controllerMethod4(Model model){

    }

    //mapping
    String controllerMethod5(Model model){
    }

    }
```

There are many such controllers
In Each return JSP page of every controller,i have `${res}` to show threads return result

Please give me approriate solution and thank you.

I kow there is **DefferedResult** concept in Spring 3.2 But it is not in Spring 3.0.
Please give me alternative solution like Deferedresult

Comment: Rather than creating threads yourself, consider using a thread pool (see the `ExecutorService` class).

Comment: I am using thread pool but important concern is that iwant result to be displayed on JSP page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I temporarily found the Solution But i want better...
My Solution :
I am using ExcecutorService with single thread creation.That service excecutes my threads one at a time.After completion of each thread,I am adding result in **Session** and after displaying session result i am removing that session attribute.

That's It!

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you do not want the model to contain the `Thread` object, you want it to contain the result computed by the thread. You need to look at the `Future` class. But even then, I doubt it will help you much; the JSP rendering code will want the result of the thread very soon after your controller method returns, so there will not be much time for the value to be computed. You need to reconsider why you are using threads at all.

Comment: Because that process requires time and we do not want to disturb user,hence we are using thread and after completion we just want to notify user that that propcess is completed

Comment: You can't do that using HTTP and plain HTML. You can not tell a user "please wait for the result.." and then some time later replace that message with the actual result. HTTP is a request-response protocol, so there is no way to send an updated response to teh client (the web browser). You *can* do that using AJAX. But using threads will not help you there.

Comment: we are not showing please wait...thats why we are using thread in background and just want to show result

Comment: I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding of how HTTP and JSP work.

Comment: I want solution That DefferedResult in spring 3.2 does.but i am using Spring 3.0.So i want alternative?